# Displaying PDF Print Dialog using javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to Print PDF content which is loaded via `<object>` tag. `onClick` of a print button it should display the PDF Print Dialog. I have achieved it in InternetExplorer with the following code. But its not working in Chrome, FireFox and Safari.

Can someone help...

JavaScript:

```
var el = document.getElementById("printPDFObject");
e1.focus();
e1.print();
```

In GoogleChrome:

> e1.Print() throws exception "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.

In FireFox, `<object>` tag displaying nothing, even I tried with `iFrame.iFrame` shows the message:

> The address wasn't understood.

FireFox doesn't know how to open this address, because one of the following protocols(c) isn't associated with any program or is not allowed in this context

Comment: What have you tried thus far to remedy the issue in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari? Are you getting error messages in any, or all, of those browsers?

Comment: In Chrome - I getting error @e1.Print() unsupported method.In FF, PDF is not getting displayed in the object tag..Getting message FF doesn't know to the file address

Comment: Please edit your post and add as much detail as you can; otherwise the SO community will not be able to help you.  This includes, but not limited to, any error messages, like those you mentioned in your comment.